# Multidimensional Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

On $\mathbb{T}$, we have approximation series $\{f_n\}$ of $f\in L^p,p\in[1,\infty)$ in the form of $f_n(x)=\sum_{|k|\le n}a_{n,k}e^{ikx}$, converging to $f$ in $L^p$. (for example, we can consider convolution with Fejer kernel)

Can we do something similar for $\mathbb{T}^n$ as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summability is no problem, for example if $K_n(t)$ is the Fejer kernel then $K_n(s)K_n(t)$ is an approximate identity on $\Bbb T^2$. Now, *convergence* for multiple Fourier series is a serious problem...

Comment: Then, is it known whether such approximation can be convergent in $L^p$?

Comment: @C.Park Yes. Convergence in $L^p$ $(p<\infty)$ follows from it being an "approximate identity". On any locally compact abelian group, if $\chi_n$ satisfies $\chi_n\ge0$, $\int \chi_n=1$, and $\chi_n\to 0$ uniformly on $G\setminus V$ for every neighborhood $V$ of the identity, then $f*\chi_n\to  f$ in $L^p$ (for $f\in L^p$, $p<1$).

Comment: Thank you very much. Besides, did I understand correctly - 'difficult on convergence for multiple Fourier series comes from that the multiple Fourier series is not obtained from such approximate identity' ?

Comment: Even in one variable convergence is much harder than summabililtty! The two cnoditions $\chi_n\ge0$, $\int\chi_n=1$ above  can be replaced by just $||\chi_n||_1\le c$ with no problem. But iif $D_n$ is the Dirichlet kernel then $||D_n||_1\to\infty$. So $D_n$ is  not  an approximate identity, and yes that's what makes convergence of Fourier series hard.